# Use Name Manager to create dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic range that starts at row 4, spans across A to G, and goes down x amount of times. The static way to refer to this is:

```
=Data!$A$4:$G$99
```

I would like to have this name dynamically calculate its contents rather than hard-code `4` to `99`.

I looked at [Offset](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) and was not able to get it working:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A$4:$G$4,0,0,COUNTA(Data!$A4:$G4),1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right formula would be:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A$4,0,0,COUNTA(Data!$A:$G),8)
```

the `width`should be set to `8`, because of the number of columns from `A` to `G`.
see if it works.

### Update

If you want it to include the columns and rows out of the range you specified, then you can try this formula:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A$4,0,0,1000,1000)
```

meaning:
**$A$4**: is the starting cell reference where your first value sits.

the two zeros can change the place of your starting cell reference. (this we don't want to do, therefore there are zeros).

The first **1000** is the height, starting from the $A$4, means the number of rows you need to look at (up and down).

 the second **1000** is the number of width, number of columns from left to right, always starting from the $A$4 reference.

so this formula will look at all the 1000 rows starting from `A4` and all the 1000 columns to the right of `A4`.

you can obviously adjust that **1000** to fit in the possible range that you want to cover.

Comment: for me it works fine. I can't understand the scenario you are trying to set.

Comment: could you add Columns() to the end to help prevent that static variable 8?

Comment: @JayRizzi: why prevent it?

Comment: @ahc maybe prevent is a bad word, I suppose I'm asking why not make the entire statement dynamic, and replace that static variable with logic? i worded that whole comment wrong , should of said "Would it make sense to replace 8 with columns(Data!$A:$G) so that the entire statement is dynamic?"

Comment: @JayRizzi: so you mean , you may have fewer or more columns? so that you want this change to be reflected in that statement?

Comment: i'm just asking whats the best practice here, would a fully dynamic statement be less prone to breakage (client places data outside range specified)

Comment: @JayRizzi: try to see if my update to the answer helps to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
=OFFSET(Data!$A$4:$G$4,,,COUNTA(Data!$A:$A),)
```

Comment: the problem with formula is when you don't have values in column `A` but you have in other columns, it doesn't take them into account. You should have values in `A` to be able to take into account those in corresponding row in other columns.